# How solve equations about projection matrix

Tags: matrix, graphics, projection

I'm read book about Computer Graphics with OpenGL (4th ed.) these formula come from  Normalized Perspective-Projection

[image: perspective-projection transform to normalized perspective-projection]

[image: there are matrix]

there are three equations:

[image: there are three equations]

and the book gives the parametric answer directly

there are four parameters:
[image: there are four parameters]

I can only figure out S_z,I can't solve the equation for the other three parameters, who can give the detailed procedure of solving the equation

Comment: You have to explain what the parameters are, and what is known and unknown.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I update the question formula (38) comes from the matrix of the projection transformation